# How to find out my file location during FTP file transfer

Tags: java, ftp

I have used this code

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException; 
public class FTPClientExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try {

            client.connect("hostname");
            client.login("user", "pwd");
            String filename = "D:\\Task\\try.txt";
            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            client.storeFile(filename, fis);
            client.logout();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when i run this,i get the message task complete.But i couldnt find out which folder i should look for the file.some one pls help me?

Comment: you have specified path "D:\\Task\\try.txt", so look there

Comment: actually i made a blunder there..                                            String filename = "D:\\Task\\try.txt";                                 String remote = "root";
fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
client.storeFile(remote, fis); still the file cant be found in root folder

Comment: @HarmeetSingh its a linux machine and i dnt know how to mention the folder structure

Comment: in linux "D:\\Task\\try.txt" its "/media/drive_name/filename.txt" linke in my computer "/media/blackPanther/try.txt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to upload on the path `D:\\Task\\try.txt` .I guess that is your source file path.
You should write something like

```
client.storeFile(ftpPath + filename, fis);
```

where ftpPath should be the FTP server location where you want to upload the file.

Edit:: File path structure

```
ftp://"+username+":"+password+"@"+ip+"/"+dir+"/"+fileName
```

Answer (score 0):

OK change

`String filename = "D:\\Task\\try.txt";`
to `String filename = "/home/user_name/Desktop";`where `user_name` is your **user name for linux** .. give it a try the file should be on your **Desktop** and remember **linux is case sensitive**.

In case of linux the path `String filename = "D:\\Task\\try.txt";` changes to `String filename = "/media/your_drive_name/try.txt";`

[here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-file-system-structure/) is linux directory structure explained.